# Typescript extend HTMLIFrameElement

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using a youtube Iframe which has the attribute `type`, apparently `type` isn't a property that exists on Iframe. How would I add this attribute to the Iframe type definition?

The definition of the Iframe in my react component:

```html
<iframe 
    id="ytplayer" 
    type="text/html"
    src={someSource}
    frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
```

The Error that TS is throwing:

```
Property 'type' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<IframeHTMLAttributes<HTMLIFrameElement>, HTMLIFrameElement>'
```

I have tried something like the following to little avail:

```
interface HTMLIFrameElement {
  type?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

I misunderstood and thought that you wanted to add non-standard properties to the `iframe` and not that YouTube provides it already with the `type` property.

In this case, the `type` property can be safely ignored and removed as it will not change the `iframe`'s behavior in any way.

**Original Answer**

Instead of adding a non-standard property to an `iframe`, I would suggest to use a data attribute.

[Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) allow you to add extra data to HTML elements without hacking their types and TypeScript fully supports them.

Data attributes are prefixed with `data-`, so in your case, you would end up with:

```
<iframe 
    id="ytplayer" 
    data-type="text/html"
    src={someSource}
    frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attribute globally, like so:

```
declare global {
    interface HTMLIFrameElement {
        type?: string;
    }
}
```

That way the attribute should be added to the global `HTMLIFrameElement` interface. Also, after Typescript sees this declaration once, this attribute will always be available on this interface, so if you want to use it in other places in your code, you can place this declaration somewhere near the top of your bundle.

Comment: thanks for the reply, however, this doesn't appear to work